# jQuery Add Class to Element When it Has Certain Other Class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find all dropdown menus on a page, and if they have the class ".active" (or ".active.visible"), then add another class ".input--filled"

This should be pretty simple, but I haven't been able to make it work yet.

I've tried:

```
$('.ui.multiple.search.selection.dropdown.active.visible).addClass('input-filled')
```

I thought this would be a nice elegant solution but it didn't work, so I tried:

```
$('.dropdown').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('visible')){
        $(this).addClass('input--filled'); 
    };
});
```

Here are some CodePens of my attempts so far:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgBQxR?editors=1111

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAjXpP?editors=1111

Comment: Your second code should work fine, the issue is that it only executes once on page-load. You need to add it to a listener, so your code knows *when* to check if the dropdown is visible. Whatever event you have that is adding/removing the class `visible` is where I'd suggest implementing adding/removing the `input--filled` class.

Comment: Why you used multiple class consecutive in selector. One of them is enough. Like `$('.dropdown.active').addClass('input-filled')`

Comment: @Santi - Ah yes of course! Thank you.

Comment: @Mohammed - You're right, I can probably use fewer, but there are other dropdowns on the page that I don't want to target.

Comment: The `visible` and `active` classes seems to be added (or removed) by `semantic.min.js` on user action... You should look at the code inspector and decide when and where you want to add the `input--filled` class. It probably will be onchange of `#input-6`...

Answer (score -2):

**Update:**
I didn't pay attention closely on what you asked. I check the semantic-ui Api and ended up with the following approach. I hope you find it useful. By the way, if you have many of these on your page, you may want to use ID selector for them, if they behave differently.

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
    forceSelection: false,
    onShow: function() {
      var $dropDown = $(this);
      $dropDown.addClass("input-filled")
    },
    onHide: function() {
      var $dropDown = $(this);
      $dropDown.removeClass("input-filled")
    }
});
```

This is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pournejati/pen/wzQqPE?editors=1111) implementing this sample.